# multi threading using vc++11

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2012, c++11, thread-safety

I have a few questions about multi threading, I am new to c++11 multi threading.

1. I want to move some blocks of my algorithm to a different thread, however, once inside the block, the operations should perform sequentially. For example, one thread tokenize string and other thread convert these tokens to double/float.
   What is the most optimum way of achieving this. I know of std::lock but then, it comes at a cost. How about atomic ?
2. Will it be more optimum if I create threads in separate core ? VS2012 has parallel_for/parallel_for_each that uses cores.
3. What are the criteria to consider when to use parallel_for/parallel_for_each and std::thread ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first point what you are looking for is a multi-threaded locking queue which you use as a buffer and communications medium between threads. With this you can form an assembly line of processing, much like in a real life factory, with each thread taking elements to process from one queue and putting the result onto another queue.

The simplest thing to try in that case is to make a class that uses some sort of queue, `std::deque` for instance, that is being protected from concurrent accesses by a `std::mutex`, and uses a `std::condition_variable` or other such mechanism for notifying when there's data available in a queue (for the consumer).

Then implement your algorithm with these new blocks and benchmark it to see if it is actually faster, since with modern processors and caches it may just be easier to make the algorithm single threaded and just run it several times in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you simply don't want to use separate threads for a simple sequence like tokenizing a string, then converting the tokens to double.

Rather the contrary, when you're splitting a task across threads, you want to find things that *don"t* need to be done sequentially. Quite the contrary, you generally want to minimize the interactions between your threads as much as possible.

As such, instead of having one thread tokenize, and another convert to double, what you'd generally prefer would be to do the tokenizing and conversion to double together, but break the input up into several large chunks of data, each if which will be processed by a single thread.

Even this may well end up doing little (if any) real good. I'd start by writing the code in a single thread, then do some profiling. Given the small amount of processing involved in tokenizing and converting data, chances are pretty good that a single thread will be able to process fast enough to use all the available memory bandwidth. In such a case, using more threads is unlikely to do an real good unless you're using a system where multiple threads might (for example) be running on entirely separate processors, so your available memory bandwidth scales (to at least some degree) along with the cores you use.

Multiple threads will (at least potentially, and usually also in fact) run on multiple cores. `parallel_for`/`parallel_for_each` are intended to simplify parallel processing for some special cases, so you get the effect of multiple threads without having to jump through nearly as many flaming hoops to ensure correct behavior.

The obvious criteria to qualify good uses of `std::thread` instead of parallel_for (or similar) would be when you want the threads to do heterogeneous processing. parallel_for basically just takes iterations of a loop and executes them in parallel. If your processing doesn't (mostly) happen in a single loop like that, `std::thread` is likely to yield better results.